# VBA second match with two column criteria

Tags: vba, match, multiple-columns

I'm trying to develop a code that brings the nth matching which is selected by the user, I already found a code that execute this but only with only one column

I want to get the third occurence of string "castro" but with the row value a2 which is "19". any suggestions?

below is the code I used to get the second ocurrence but only using one column.

```
      Sub test1()
      Dim teste As String
      teste = VLOOKUPNTH("prysmian", Range("B1:C22"), 2, 2)
      End Sub

      Function VLOOKUPNTH(lookup_value, table_array As Range, col_index_num 
      As Integer, nth_value)

      Dim nRow As Long
      Dim nVal As Integer
      Dim bFound As Boolean

      VLOOKUPNTH = "No Match"

      With table_array
      For nRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
      If .Cells(nRow, 1).Value = lookup_value Then
        nVal = nVal + 1
      End If
        If nVal = nth_value Then
            VLOOKUPNTH = .Cells(nRow, col_index_num).Text
            Exit Function
        End If
      Next nRow
      End With
      End Function


     the table 
     A       B      C
     a1    castro   1
     a1    castro   3
     a1    castro   4
     a1    castro   5
     a1    castro   6
     a1    castro   7
     a2    castro   17
     a2    castro   18
     a2    castro   19
     a2    castro   20
     a2    castro   21
     a2    castro   22
     a2    castro   23
```

Comment: Sorry, but this makes no sense to me. You want the 3rd 'Castro' row (which I assume has a '4' in column c), so how do you get down to the '19'? I assume the last *row* in your table is 13 (col c = 23)?

Comment: I want the 3rd "castro" row but in the same row it has the value "a2"

Comment: And is 'a2' some value that will: (a) never change; will always search for 'a2'; or (b) can be 'a3' or 'a4', etc.?  In other words, you should describe the rules associated with your search... It makes a big difference in how you solve the code problem.

Comment: Also, the range you pass does NOT include column A -- which is where 'a2' can be found. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: the range I passed represent the code that I applied by using only column B and C....

The rules for this code is:

Comment: the range I passed represent the code that I applied by using only column B and C....

The rules for this code is:
I would like to use vlookup and use two columns as criterias 
the first column has to search "a2" value and the other column would use the 3rd "castro" row that has already "a2" value, is like index + match code

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code so that it will check two columns.

```
1. Changed the range to include column A
2. Changed the column offsets to allow for the added column.





Option Explicit

Sub test1()
  Dim teste     As String
  teste = VLOOKUPNTH("castro", Range("A1:C22"), 3, 3)
  Debug.Print "Result: " & teste
End Sub

Function VLOOKUPNTH(lookup_value, table_array As Range, col_index_num As Integer, nth_value As Integer) As String

Dim nRow As Long
Dim nVal As Integer
Dim bFound As Boolean

    VLOOKUPNTH = "No Match"

    With table_array
        For nRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
            ' Must match both columns to be counted.
            If .Cells(nRow, 2).Value = lookup_value And .Cells(nRow, 1).Value = "a2" Then
                nVal = nVal + 1
            End If
            If nVal = nth_value Then
                ' Now we have found the nth occurence of the lookup value.
                VLOOKUPNTH = .Cells(nRow, col_index_num).Text
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next nRow
    End With
End Function
```